# Boost Property ptree: boost write_xml adding unicode 0x0 character in child element in xml file

Tags: c++, xml, boost, unicode, boost-propertytree

I am using boost `write_xml` function to create xml. I am able to create successful xml using Boost. But It is adding extra unicode 0x0 character at end of xml child element.

code snippet:

```
boost::property_tree::write_xml(oss, pt, boost::property_tree::xml_writer_make_settings<std::string>(' ', 4));
```

I am sending this xml to Java Side application and Java throwing below exception error while parsing boost created xml.

[An Invalid XML character(Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33625458/an-invalid-xml-characterunicode-0x0-was-found-in-the-element-content-of-the-d)

Anyone know, how to remove `unicode 0x0 character` from XML while creating xml using `boost property ptree`.

Comment: this is new to me, why would write_xml write an 0x0 code point ? maybe *your* original property tree instance contained 0 chars before writing to xml ? ( property_tree uses std::basic_string that in turn can store 0 chars ) please, post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data has embedded NUL bytes. One way to achieve this:

```
std::string const hazard("erm\0", 4); 
boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
pt.put("a.b.c.<xmlattr>.d", hazard);
```

### UPDATE

Upon closer inspection, NUL-bytes are simply ***not supported*** in XML, full stop ([Storing the value Null (ASCII) in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38012034/storing-the-value-null-ascii-in-xml/38012808#38012808)).

Either get rid of the offending byte, or use some kind of encoding, like base64.

---

Old analysis and demonstration follows

Mind you, Property Tree is not an XML library, and as such could have limitations that don't conform to the XML standard.

I still think this is a BUG, since it doesn't roundtrip: Property Tree cannot read its own serialized property tree back:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9612ce3405c428d6)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string const hazard("erm\0", 4); 

    {
        std::ofstream ofs("NULbyte.xml");

        boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
        pt.put("a.b.c.<xmlattr>.d", hazard);

        write_xml(ofs, pt);
    }
    {
        std::ifstream ifs("NULbyte.xml");

        boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
        read_xml(ifs, pt);
        std::cout << (hazard == pt.get<std::string>("a.b.c.<xmlattr>.d")) << "\n";
    }
}
```

You can correctly use the JSON backend if you want: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e20a6dfabe9da06)</kbd>**